# Java Regex for international phone number

Tags: java, regex, validation, phone-number

Please assist, I need a regex that can validate +27 11 123 4567 . The regex pattern I have currently is :

```
if(phoneNo.matches("\\+d{3}[-\\.\\s]\\d{2}[-\\.\\s]\\d{3}[-\\.\\s]\\d{4}")) return true;
```

Comment: Some country codes are 3 digits e.g Ireland and Portugal

Comment: In this case, I think I would go the easy route and just validate `\+(\s?\d+)+` for a String starting with a + and 1 or more groups containing possibly a leading space and 1 or more digits.